# Resize a collection of different sized png images to the same dimensions

Tags: image-format, resize, photoshop-scripting

I have a collection of a few hundred png images, each are different dimensions.

I want to be able to resize them all to the same dimensions, preferably keeping the aspect ratio intact.

Is it possible to write a script to automate this?  Any pointers in the right direction or advice would be more than welcome as I am not sure where to start.

I have Photoshop and Illustrator.

Thanks.

Comment: Which platform and which version of Photoshop? You can definitely script this, but the platform and version are necessary to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Phil, I have Photoshop & Illustrator CS5 (the whole CS5 suite), running on Mac OS X.  Let me know if you need any more info? Thanks.

Comment: @Alan has a correct answer here. I am a Big Nerd so I would write my own Applescript to do this, but there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dr. Brown's Image Processor. There's a version in Bridge and a more sophisticated version for CS5 [here](http://russellbrown.com/scripts.html) on his website. It allows you to specify a dimension for the output, and even run an action on each image as it's processed. The "Pro" version adds various capabilities you may not need for your purposes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Alan, after looking at the website, am I correct in thinking that the scripts can't output in the format of png?

Comment: Image Processor Pro (the one in Dr. Brown's Services) definitely does PNG. It's the one at the top of the list on this page: http://russellbrown.com/tips_tech.html